# Arial Black Italic font causing WinForms application to crash

Tags: winforms, fonts

A WinForms application that I maintain crashes on a very small fraction of user machines (probably about 4 to date).  The application crashes every time for those users, and it crashes before the very first dialog gets displayed.

**Exception**

```
Source:
System.Drawing

Message:
Font 'Arial Black' does not support style 'Bold'.

Stack Trace:
at System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont()
at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet)
```

One of the fonts that the application uses is Arial Black:

```
this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Black", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

The first time this crash happened, I noticed a font that was on the user's computer, but not mine.  It was called “Arial Black Italic” and it was dated 1997.  This was the filename:

> ARBLI___.TTF

[image]

*The user had Windows XP.*

I deleted the font, and afterwards the application ran fine.  As I mentioned, over the past 22 months, this crash happened to about 3 other users.  Each time deleting the “Arial Black Italic” font from the user's computer seemed to fix the problem.

*The most recent time, the user had Windows 7 and the font was date much newer, yet the aforementioned protocol still resolved the problem.*

**At this point, I am trying to figure out the root cause of this crash bug and how to prevent it.**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create regular font first.
            // Depending on the user's system, this font may already be bold.
            //

            var theFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
                "Arial Black",
                8.25F,
                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                ( ( byte )( 0 ) )
                );

            // If font is not bold, then try to create it.
            //

            if ( ( null != theFont ) && !theFont.Bold )
            {
                if ( theFont.FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable( FontStyle.Bold ) )
                {
                    theFont = new Font( theFont, FontStyle.Bold );
                }
            }

            // Now use the font.
            //

            this.label3.Font = theFont;
        }
    }
}
```